# How to escape symbols in Kotlin documentation Dokka/Kdoc?

Tags: kotlin, kdoc, kotlin-dokka

I want to add a comment like this

```
  /**
   * @param scrollFraction In range [0..1].
   */
```

But Dokka/Kdoc interprets stuff inside square brackets as a reference. This leads to badly rendered comments when you check the function's documentation in the IDE or generate the docs. How can I escape square brackets/other symbols in Dokka/Kdoc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to do it using ` symbol, like this:

```
 /**
  * @param scrollFraction In range `[0..1]`.
  */
```

However, using ` symbol will show everything in between as a code block.

To just use square brackets without a reference inside, use HTML symbols, like [ and ] from the [@yuvgin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572887/3569545).

Comment: This also typesets the contents within backticks in a code font, instead of the regular font. Therefore this answer solves the issue of the question, while introducing its own issue.

Answer (score 11):

You can use HTML escaping:

```
 /**
   * @param scrollFraction In range &#91;0..1&#93;.
   */
```

should output in Dokka as `range [0..1].`, since `&#91;` escapes as `[` and `&#93;` escapes as `]`.

Note this will not work inside a section of inline code (between grave accents - `like this`). 
 For such cases use square brackets ([ and ]) normally, as was suggested in [Demigod's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54572624/9075805).